# slickgrid dataview.setfilter not working properly

Tags: slickgrid

If I create several grids, how do I set the dataView.setFilter(filter) for ***each*** grid?

Currently when I apply dataView.Setfilter(filter), it only collects data from the last grid I created even if I push each grid to an array and then apply setFilter to grid[i].

many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating a new DataView for each grid? You should be.

Any Grid initialized with a DataView in place of a plain array will allow you to access the specific DataView using `grid.getData()`.

So to apply a filter to a specific DataView from your grid array you'd do:

```
grid[i].getData().setFilter(filter);
```